# Accuracy, Precision, Recall RMSE and MAE values are same for SVM, Naive Bayes and Random Forest

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis

I am studying on sentiment analysis of tourist reviews. 90% of reviews are positive the rest are negative.
My Accuracy, Precision, Recall RMSE, and MAE values are the same for SVM, Naive Bayes, and Random Forest. Is it possible or is there any mistake? Btw, I am using Python.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I know the site that you send of its link. But the values are the same for all of them. Maybe my mistake is regarding with TF-IDF matrix. Thank you again.

Answer (score 3):

You have improperly cast this problem as a classification problem.  See [here](https://fharrell.com/post/classification) for details.  Your real problem is one of estimating *tendencies*, i.e., probabilities.  Classification only makes sense in very narrow situations such as when the signal:noise ratio is exceptionally high.  Since you miscast the problem, all the accuracy measures you have tried will yield non-helpful results.  With probability models/probability machines you look at things like predictive discrimination and calibration.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `average='weighted'` for precision/recall and you should see some different values:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_score.html

I am not sure it is available for the other metrics.